# Count with join WHERE Count of rows in table A should be calculated for each row in table B using foreign key

Tags: mysql, join, count

I've prepared a query with multi-table joins.
I'm getting a perfect result with this query:

```
SELECT
`request`.`ID` ,  `request`.`USER_ID` ,  `donor`.`FULL_NAME` ,
`request`.`BLOOD_GROUP`, `request`.`UNITS` ,  `city`.`NAME` AS  `LOCATION`,
`city`.`ID` AS  `LOCATION_ID` ,  `request`.`DATE` ,  `request`.`EXPIRES_ON` ,
`request`.`ADDRESS` ,  `request`.`STATUS`
FROM  `request` 
JOIN  `donor` ON  `donor`.`ID` =  `request`.`USER_ID` 
JOIN  `city` ON  `city`.`ID` =  `request`.`LOCATION` 
ORDER BY  `request`.`DATE`
```

Here, I'm getting all the rows that I'm expecting...

But, this second query which has an added column count(`response.ID`) is producing a single row with count 1, as there is only one row present in `response` table.

This is the modified query:

```
SELECT 
`request`.`ID` ,  `request`.`USER_ID` ,  `donor`.`FULL_NAME` ,
`request`.`BLOOD_GROUP` ,  `request`.`UNITS` ,  `city`.`NAME` AS  `LOCATION` ,
`city`.`ID` AS  `LOCATION_ID` ,  `request`.`DATE` ,  `request`.`EXPIRES_ON` ,
`request`.`ADDRESS` ,  `request`.`STATUS`, count(`response`.`ID`) AS `RESPONSE`
FROM  `request` 
JOIN  `donor` ON  `donor`.`ID` =  `request`.`USER_ID` 
JOIN  `city` ON  `city`.`ID` =  `request`.`LOCATION`
JOIN `response` ON `response`.`REQUEST_ID` = `request`.`ID`
ORDER BY  `request`.`DATE`
```

What I expect here is that the query returns all the rows from `request` table and return counts from `response` whether it be 0 or any whole number.

I tried to use the strategy used in other questions but things didn't work.
Please, suggest me if their is any solution to this.
If nothing, then I got only one option, that'd be making another query just for count.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join instead of an inner join.

```
SELECT 
    `request`.`ID` ,  `request`.`USER_ID` ,  `donor`.`FULL_NAME` ,
    `request`.`BLOOD_GROUP` ,  `request`.`UNITS` ,  `city`.`NAME` AS  `LOCATION` ,
    `city`.`ID` AS  `LOCATION_ID` ,  `request`.`DATE` ,  `request`.`EXPIRES_ON` ,
    `request`.`ADDRESS` ,  `request`.`STATUS`, count(`response`.`ID`) AS `RESPONSE`
FROM  `request` 
    JOIN  `donor` ON  `donor`.`ID` =  `request`.`USER_ID` 
    JOIN  `city` ON  `city`.`ID` =  `request`.`LOCATION`
    LEFT JOIN `response` ON `response`.`REQUEST_ID` = `request`.`ID`
ORDER BY  `request`.`DATE`
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I tried LEFT JOIN too, but produces same result.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped me with a better and resource friendly solution.

The count row that I'm querying is statistical and wholly depends on any row inserted into or deleted from the `response` table.
So rather than running a complex query, he suggested to add `RESPONSE` column in `request` table and update values on insertion or deletion.

So, I changed my program and wrote an UPDATE query after both INSERT and DELETE query on `response` table.

Sometimes, simple solutions are way better than complex approaches.

Thanks.